# how to find the mode of an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, mode

I know there are a lot of threads of this question but none of them has helped me the way i wanted.

So here is my problem: I have this array:

```
int [] array = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4}
```

I want to show the mode of that array but when i do it, it shows three 1's and one 2 and it should be one 1 and one 2, i want to save the 2 numbers (1 and 2) in a `ListBox` and the number 4 in another `ListBox`.

I found this code but i didn't fully understand it. I don't know how to use a dictionary and i cannot use it because i do not know how it works:

```
int[] numsArr = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < numsArr.Length; i++)
    if (dic.ContainsKey(numsArr[i]))
        dic[numsArr[i]] = ++dic[numsArr[i]];
    else
        dic.Add(numsArr[i], 1);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> kvp in dic)
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Number {0} has {1} repetitions.", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I think I got what you wrote, but please be clearer about actual and expected output.

Comment: I am confused because (as i understand it) the mode is the single value that appears most often in a set of data but you describe the output as two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] numsArr = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var numberGroups = numsArr.GroupBy(num => num);
var mostCommonGroups = numberGroups.Where(grp => grp.Count() == numberGroups.Max(group => group.Count()));

var mostCommonValues = mostCommonGroup.Select(mostCommonGroups.Key);
```

The most common values are your modes.